# Correlation between words

Tags: classification, correlation

I have a classification of my clients (A, B, C) and now someone proposed a new method of doing this classification. I would like to check how correlated are the results of both methods.

I tried to use excell correl function but I guess it does not work with text ...

Comment: Couldn't you just check what percentage of clients that are identically classified in both methods? Correlation might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Do a Cohen's Kappa test. And welcome to the site.